# ¿Cómo agregar valores a un campo que tiene restricciones?

Tags: sql

Éste es mi código para agregar la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE oficinas (
oficina INT PRIMARY KEY,
ciudad TEXT(30),
region TEXT(20),
dir INT CONSTRAINT cf_dir REFERENCES empleados,
objetivo CURRENCY,
ventas CURRENCY);
```

Y éste es el código con el cual intento agregar un registro:

```
INSERT INTO oficinas(oficina, ciudad, region, dir, objetivo, ventas)
VALUES(10, 'Monterrey', 'Noroeste', 12,150, 100);
```

Me pueden ayudar porfavor, no tengo idea de qué tengo que poner al campo dir...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el campo "dir" has de meter un número, pero ese número ha de corresponder con un valor de la tabla empleados en la columna que sea primary key

Echále un vistazo a esto: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clave_for%C3%A1nea

Comment: Yá está, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

A la hora de insertar una oficina, solo tienes una columna que haga referencia a otra tabla así que ahí está el problema. Cuando insertas un empleado, ese empleado hace referencia a un empleado que existe, es decir, tú has insertado el empleado número 12, si en la tabla empleados no hay ningún empleado con ese *ID* te va a dar error porque ese empleado no existe. Tu `insert` está bien hecha, lo único que tienes que preocuparte es que el campo `dir` exista en algún `ID` de empleados.

Comment: ya, muchas gracias ;)